# How to customize Table Of Content in report viewer - Active Report 6.0

Tags: c#, reporting

I am working on an Windows application and i have a report, I want to customize Active report viewer **Tables Of Contents without Thumbnail Tab**.

So please suggest me to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The customization of just the TOC without thumbnail is not possible.
The customization is applied on both or none of the tabs. In order to set the properties of the TOC of report, please refer to the following documentation link :
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports.Viewer6~DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Viewer.TableOfContentsObject.html

Regards,
Mohita

Answer (score 0):

To customize the tableOfContent in Active Report viewer, firstly we have to get all control from viewer and then get the Tab Control and work on TabPage.

```
var controls = viewer1.Controls.Cast<Control>();
foreach (Control control in controls)

    {
      // Check fot TableOfContents Control
      if (control.Name == "TableOfContents")
     {
                            // Getting the TabControl.
                            var contColletion = control.Controls;
                            Control tabCollection = contColletion[0];
                            TabControl tabControl = (TabControl)tabCollection;
                            tabControl.Appearance = TabAppearance.Normal;
                            // Remove the Thumbnail Tab from Control.
                            tabControl.TabPages.RemoveAt(1);
                        }
                    }
```